# how to show different custom cell in a table view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**1. in my method in write code example given below -**

```
        (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier2 = @"SimpleTableCell2";
        if (indexPath.row== 0) {


        SimpleTableCell *cell = nil;
        cell=(SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
           cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            SimpleTableCell2 *cell2 = nil;
            cell2=(SimpleTableCell2 *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier2];
        }
        if (cell2 == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell2" owner:self options:nil];
           cell2 = [nib2 objectAtIndex:0];
        }


        cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.prepTimeLabel.text = @"detail";// [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"creme_brelee.jpg"];
        cell2.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }
```

can any one help me am i write correct code becoz it will give an error 
    the error is use of undeclear identifier cell and cell2 
    i dont understand what is this error 
    it gives the error after making cell2 before cell2 it works perfectly 
    help me
    thanks

Comment: SimpleTableCell2 *cell2 = nil; not to take in if conditaion

Answer (score 1):

It is giving the error because you have declared it like this:

```
if (indexPath.row== 0) {
    SimpleTableCell *cell = nil;
    cell=(SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
```

and you are using the cell variable outside the local scope of this condition.
Do this:

`SimpleTableCell *cell = nil;
if (indexPath.row== 0) 
{
        cell=(SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }`

Also make sure that you have imported the header SimpleTableCell.h.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (indexPath.row== 0) {


        SimpleTableCell *cell = nil;
        cell=(SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
           cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
return cell;    
}




     if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            SimpleTableCell2 *cell2 = nil;
            cell2=(SimpleTableCell2 *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier2];

    if (cell2 == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell2" owner:self options:nil];
           cell2 = [nib2 objectAtIndex:0];
        }
return cell2;        
}

 UITableViewCell *commonCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"commonToALL"];
    if (commonCell == nil) {
        commonCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"commonToALL"];


    }
return commonCell;
```

Try This. This will create two specific cell for index 0 and 1 while two general Cells for remainder as you have 4 rows.

Comment: ok but  cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; its give undeclear identifier cell error

Comment: Alright how many rows do you have. I mean what do you return in numberOfRows method?

Comment: again crash Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.'
give these error i have already import .h file

Comment: Ok! I should really see the whole code now may be your cell is initializing wrong way!

Comment: ok can i mail u my project give me your mail id or have u use skype than give me skype id

Comment: Ok send it at viks9273@gmail.com

Comment: i have sent it plz review it

Answer (score 0):

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
   SimpleTableCell2 *cell2 = nil;
   cell2=(SimpleTableCell2 *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier2];
   //This is ok
   cell2.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
}
//No you cant access outside
cell2.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Here, you have declared `cell2` inside the if block. So you can use this variable in this scope only. When you try to access cell2 outside, you will get use of undeclared error.

Answer (score 0):

Undeclared identifier means that you didn't register cell class.
You should do that in **viewDidLoad**:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tableView registerClass:[SimpleTableCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[SimpleTableCell2 class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell2"];
}
```

However, **NSStringFromClass** approach is better when dealing with cell identifiers:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tableView registerClass:NSStringFromClass([SimpleTableCell class]) forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:NSStringFromClass([SimpleTableCell2 class]) forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell2"];
}
```

If you didn't register a cell class, **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** can return **nil**, as specified in the docs:

```
This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one
using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available
for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.
```

Additional note: keep your view controller methods as slim as possibile.

Answer (score 0):

you could try these codes:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier2 = @"SimpleTableCell2";
if (indexPath.row== 0) {
    SimpleTableCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text = @"detail";// [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"creme_brelee.jpg"];

    return cell;
}

SimpleTableCell2 *cell2 = nil;
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    cell2 = (SimpleTableCell2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier2];
    if (cell2 == nil){
        NSArray *nib2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell2" owner:self options:nil];
        cell2 = [nib2 objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell2.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell2;
```

}

Comment: after trying this code  app crash give error  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
how i resolve this

Comment: reply i m waiting for reply

Comment: you see the SimpleTableCell and SimpleTableCell2;how did you add thumbnailImageView,prepTimeLabel,nameLabel?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better check you custom cell's tag in SimpleTableCell.xib
[image]

whether the tag is 0

and just one custom cell could work like:

```
    (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
       cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text = @"detail";// [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"creme_brelee.jpg"];
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        [cell.thumbnailImageView.image setHidden:Yes];
        [cell.prepTimeLabel.text setHidden:Yes];
    }
    return cell;
}
```